# MySQL How can I UPDATE only a subset of a table (907000 rows)

Tags: mysql

I have a table (FEV) with 907,000 records.
I need to update a field in this table with info from another table (CS).
I cannot join the 2 tables using their PK. I need to join them using a calculation like this:

```
fev.value=cs.cpossi
```

cpossi is actually a calculated field `concat(cpo,'-ssi') as cpossi`

**SELECT**

```
SELECT * from
ost_form_entry_values fev 
inner join 
(select *, concat(cpo,'-ssi') as cpossi from cpo_ssi) cs 
on fev.value=cs.cpossi
where value like '%-ssi';
```

***19 row(s) returned   0.234 sec / 0.000 sec***

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE
ost_form_entry_values fev 
inner join 
(select *, concat(cpo,'-ssi') as cpossi from cpo_ssi) cs 
on fev.value=cs.cpossi
SET fev.value=cs.SSI 
where value like '%-ssi';
```

***Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query   30.000 sec***

The update times out at 30 sec, because the query is not limited at the join, like it was in the SELECT. It is limited at the UPDATE level. This means that it probably returns all 907,000 records to the UPDATE command.

How can I overcome this?

PS:

```
CREATE TABLE `cpo_ssi` (
   `CPO` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `SSI` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ticket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `ticket_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`CPO`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `ost_form_entry_values` (
  `entry_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `value_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`,`field_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

...

```
Explain Select command above:
1 SIMPLE cs ALL 332 90.00 Using where 
1 UPDATE fev ALL 907629 1.11 Using where
```

...

```
Explain Update command above:
1   SIMPLE  cs      ALL                 332 90.00   Using where
1   UPDATE  fev     ALL                 907629  1.11    Using where
```

...

Comment: how many rows in cpo_ssi?

Comment: only 332 rows in cpo_ssi

Comment: what does `explain SELECT * from
ost_form_entry_values fev 
inner join 
(select *, concat(cpo,'-ssi') as cpossi from cpo_ssi) cs 
on fev.value=cs.cpossi
where value like '%-ssi'` show?

Comment: Shows 19 records where the 2 tables match with the join specified. e.g. if fev.value ='123-ssi' and cs.cpo = '123' then there is a match, in which case the fev.value is replaced with the cpo.SSI

Comment: I think you missed the "explain" at the beginning

Comment: Sorry : 1 SIMPLE cpo_ssi  ALL     332 100.00 
1 SIMPLE fev  ALL     907629 1.11 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

Comment: ah, if you have mysql 5.6 or mariadb 10.0.5 or above, you can do `explain update...` on your original update and maybe that will show why it is not working correctly.  if you do, could you add that (and the `explain select...` output) to your question (not as a comment)?

Comment: 1 SIMPLE cs  ALL     332 90.00 Using where
1 UPDATE fev  ALL     907629 1.11 Using where

Answer (score 2):

After 3 hours, I think the best solution to this issue is to use TEMPORARY TABLES which make use of the existing Primary Keys of the table to be updated.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_cpossi`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_cpossi
SELECT fev.entry_id, fev.field_id, cs.SSI FROM
`ost_form_entry_values` fev 
INNER JOIN
`cpo_ssi` cs 
ON fev.`value`=CONCAT(cs.cpo,'-ssi')
WHERE fev.`value` LIKE '%-ssi' AND cs.SSI IS NOT NULL;
   
UPDATE
`ost_form_entry_values` fev 
INNER JOIN
`temp_cpossi` cs 
ON
fev.entry_id=cs.entry_id and fev.field_id=cs.field_id
SET fev.`value`=cs.SSI 
WHERE fev.`value` LIKE '%-ssi' AND cs.SSI IS NOT NULL;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_cpossi`;
```

We first create the table and make sure it includes the 2 PK already existing in the ost_form_entry_values table, plus we add the field we will later use to update the table. This field of course comes from the other table.

This time the update is instantaneous.

1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  0.063 sec

If you have a better solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing the subquery?  Just do:

```
UPDATE cpo_ssi cs
join ost_form_entry_values fev
on fev.value=concat(cs.cpo,'-ssi')
SET fev.value=cs.SSI
```

if you want it to read cpo_ssi and find ost_form_entry_values that match.

Though this would benefit from an index on ost_format_entry_values.value.  I would suggest you do:

```
alter table ost_format_entry_values add index value_index (value);
```

Comment: Does not reduce timings

Comment: which one, both?

Comment: Cannot make value a PK because it is free form and contains duplicates and NULLs

Comment: I didn't suggest making it a pk, just an index?

Comment: Error Code: 1170. BLOB/TEXT column 'value' used in key specification without a key length